# Call alerts integration with Prometheus Alertmanager

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

im setting Prometheus as a monitoring system, with Alertmanager. As an alert i need service that will call on selected number or group of numbers.

Best solution for us would be not to have an 3rd party provider who is gonna be covering this for us.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus doesn't call phone numbers. (Nor does it send SMS, for that matter.) You need to either write your own [webhook handler](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/#webhook_config) (i.e. an HTTP server) that then makes an API call to a 3rd party provider.

The other option is to hook up your Alertmanager to a service like Opsgenie/Pagerduty that includes phone calls as an option to get notifications.

That being said, I don't think any of these options will be free (as in beer).